# Organization Browser - Specific User

Tags: organization-browser

In a previous post it was asked:

I have added an Organization browser to a page. What I am wondering, is how I can have the browser begin with a specifc user and not the viewing user?

With the answer given:

add the 'accountname' parameter to your URL:

http://www.example.com/orgbrowser.aspx?accountname=domain/useraccount

I did that but it didn't work. It still provides the signed in user's view.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble, but eventually found this post and it worked for SharePoint Online.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37576.organizational-browser-start-account.aspx

It also has the option for Onprem:

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally for me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function CreateHierarchyChartControl(parentId, profileId, type, persistControlId, flowDirection, silverLightControlId)
{
    profileId = "WINDOWS\\username"; //added line

    var initParam = profileId + ',' + type + ',' + persistControlId + ',' + flowDirection + ',' + silverLightControlId;
    var host = document.getElementById(parentId);

    host.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    host.setAttribute('height', '100%');

    Silverlight.createObject('/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap',
        host,
        silverLightControlId,
        {
            top: '30',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            version: '4.0.50401.0',
            isWindowless: 'true',
            enableHtmlAccess: 'true'
        },
        {
            onLoad: OnHierarchyChartLoaded
        },
        initParam,
        null);
}

</script> ​​
```